# How to get the trajectory data?

Tags: ros, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, everyone,
I want to get the trajectory data to analyze and control the robot, but i don't know how to get them.
I did planning in the window of the planning_scene_warehouse_viewer.
Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/133661/how-to-get-the-trajectory-data?/) by [karen0603](https://answers.ros.org/users/5106/karen0603/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2014-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look up in the rosbag or  subscribe the topic and then save the data in a array or a file.

---

Originally posted by [karen0603](https://answers.ros.org/users/5106/karen0603/) with karma: 32 on 2014-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0